# iterating over in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.6

Sorry a simple question, I guess I am getting the basic looping wrong. I am not sure why I am not geting the expected result.

```
Comp = {'Red':100, 'Blue':101, 'Green':102 ,'Ivory':103, 'White':104}
Comp ['Black'] = 99

def value_for_value(d, mynumber):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        print key,value,type(value),mynumber,type(mynumber)
        mykey = 'AAA'
        if value == mynumber:
            mykey = key
    return mykey

print value_for_value(Comp,99)
```

Expected result : **Black**

Actual Results : **AAA**

PS: just to make sure that I am comparing the correct data types, I have printed the data types as well.

Comment: As a side note, it's a bad idea to name a variable `str`, since that's the name of the type and constructor for strings. And it's even more confusing to use the name `str` for an integer value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that every time through the loop, you set `mykey = 'AAA'`. So, unless `str` happens to be the last value, you will overwrite the right answer with the wrong one.

Let's add some more prints to see better:

```
def value_for_value(d, str):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        mykey = 'AAA'
        if value == str:
            mykey = key
        print key,value,type(value),str,type(str),mykey
    return mykey

>>> value_for_value(Comp, 99)
Blue 101 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> AAA
Ivory 103 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> AAA
Black 99 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> Black
Green 102 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> AAA
White 104 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> AAA
Red 100 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> AAA
'AAA'
```

---

So, how do you fix it? Simple: just move the fallback value outside the loop, so you only do it once:

```
def value_for_value(d, str):
    mykey = 'AAA'
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if value == str:
            mykey = key
        print key,value,type(value),str,type(str),mykey
    return mykey
```

Now:

```
>>> value_for_value(Comp, 99)
Blue 101 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> AAA
Ivory 103 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> AAA
Black 99 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> Black
Green 102 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> Black
White 104 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> Black
Red 100 <type 'int'> 99 <type 'int'> Black
'Black'
```

---

It's worth noting that this whole thing would be simpler if you built an inverse dict and just indexed it:

```
>>> CompInverse = {value: key for key, value in Comp.iteritems()}
>>> CompInverse.get(99, 'AAA')
'Black'
```

Comment: Thanks mate . I tried the `break` method.Though your answers works perfectly fine as well. Theinverse dictionary option is very helful though. Will accept your answer :)

Comment: or with the same data-structure : `next((k for k,v in comp.iteritems() if v == 99),'AAA')`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clearer to write it like this:

```
def value_for_value(d, str):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if v == str:
            return k
    return 'AAA'
```

Wouldn't `key_for_value` be a more meaningful name?

Creating the inverted dict as suggested by @abarnert is a good idea if you will be doing a bunch of lookups without modifying `d`